# как разбить логику на контроллер и модель в ноде

Tags: javascript, node.js, mvc, express

Не совсем понимаю, как правильно нужно разбивать логику на controllers и models в nodeJS при работе с backend приложения. Допустим, у меня есть пример

Данный код находится в model моего приложения, и логически я понимаю, что модель отвечает только за выбор из базы, а проверку и все остальное должен выполнять контроллер, но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать и я пробовал часть кода перенести в контроллер, и экспортировать его, но у меня ничего не получилось( Прошу, помогите, хотя-бы на данном примере! Мне главное понять принцип работы с MVC в ноде!!!

Как я уже написал - >

postModejs.js

```
exports.homePage = function (req, res) {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM `posts`', function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.render('pages/home', {object: result});
  });
};

exports.currentPostPage = function(req, res){


db.query('SELECT * FROM `posts`', function (err, result) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    var post = result.filter(item => {return (item.id == req.params.id)? item: false})[0];
    if (post === undefined){
      res.render('pages/404');
    } else {
      res.render('pages/post-page', {postId: req.params.id, item: post});
    }

  });
};
```

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var login = require('./controllers/login.controller');
var register = require('./controllers/register.controller');
var db = require('./db');
var pageroutes = require('./models/pageroutes');
var controllers = require('./controllers/new-post.controller');

var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use("/public", express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

var router = express.Router();

//route to handle user registration
router.post('/register', register.register);

router.post('/login', login.login);

app.use('/api', router);

app.get('/register', pageroutes.registerPage);

app.get('/login', pageroutes.loginPage);

app.get('/', pageroutes.homePage);

app.post('/', controllers.newPost);

app.get('/post/:id', pageroutes.currentPostPage);

app.get('/contact', pageroutes.contactPage);

app.use(pageroutes.errorPage);

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю организовать код следующим образом:
В роуте '/users' вызывается метод контроллера. В прилагаемом примере контроллер - userController, а вызывается его метод - handleUsers.
Этот метод получает помощью userModel.getAll всех пользователей и выбирает из них всех с id кратным 5.
Вместо обращения к базе данных в userModel используется обращение к ресурсу.

[image: Edit 0q641z9k0w]

Comment: Ничего не понял) в примере не юзеры в посты)

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич,  мой пример абстрактный. Он про юзеров ) А что именно не понятно?
Сам код по ссылке получилось посмотреть?

Comment: Да, простите, постараюсь к вечеру разобраться, не сразу с телефона понял)